# OracleDataReader GetChars method only buffering half the characters

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am trying to read a CLOB value from an Oracle database query using the GetChars method. I am doing this so that I can buffer very large CLOB values and write the results out to an XML file.

However, there seems to be an issue where the GetChars method of an OracleDataReader is only buffering half the characters it should. This causes me to continue buffering in a loop until GetChars returns 0, but I think this is very inefficient and is slowing down my program.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Here is the fragment of code that I am using:

```
Dim reader As Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader
Dim bufferSize As Integer = 1024 * 2000
Dim outChar(bufferSize - 1) As Char

Using connection As New Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectString)
    Dim command As New Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand(statement)
    command.Connection = connection

    connection.Open()
    reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

    Do While reader.Read()
        ' Reset the starting char for a new CLOB
        startIndex = 0
        Array.Clear(outChar, 0, bufferSize)

        ' Read chars into outChar() and retain the number of bytes returned
        retval = reader.GetChars(0, startIndex, outChar, 0, bufferSize)
        Do Until retval = 0
            rawStr = New String(outChar)
            rawStr = rawStr.Replace(Chr(0), "")

            myxml.WriteRaw(rawStr)
            myxml.Flush()

            startIndex += rawStr.Length
            Array.Clear(outChar, 0, bufferSize)
            retval = reader.GetChars(0, startIndex, outChar, 0, bufferSize)
        Loop
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: Really could use any help/advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Data.OracleClient` assembly / namespace has been deprecated by Microsoft:

> [System.Data.OracleClient Namespace | MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):
>   The types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the .NET Framework.

There is a newer alternative from Oracle called [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), which is still supported. There are two NuGet packages available:

- [Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)
- [Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Entity Framework Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/)

You might also want to install [the developer tools](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html).

---

If you want to stick with the Microsoft library, you could try using [the `GetOracleLob` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getoraclelob%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. That will return [an `OracleLob` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclelob%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you can use to read the value:

```
Using lob As OracleLob = reader.GetOracleLob(0)
    Using sr As New StreamReader(lob, Text.Encoding.Unicode)
        retval = sr.Read(outChar, 0, bufferSize)
        Do Until retval = 0
            myxml.WriteRaw(outChar, 0, retval)
            myxml.Flush()

            Array.Clear(outChar, 0, retval)
            retval = sr.Read(outChar, 0, bufferSize)
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```

You might need to adjust the encoding passed to the `StreamReader` constructor. The `GetChars` method uses Unicode by default, but I suspect your string might be in a different encoding.

Looking at the code in dotPeek, this will be much more efficient than calling `GetChars`:

1. The `GetChars` method creates a new `OracleLob` on each call, and reads its `Value` property.
2. The `Value` property reads **the entire string** into memory on each call.
3. The `GetChars` method then copies the string to a `Char` array.
4. The `GetChars` method then copies the specified section of the array to the buffer you've passed in.

This is horrendously inefficient, and it's no surprise that your code is running slowly!

---

*Cross-posted from [the discussion thread on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/5096420/OracleDataReader-GetChars-method-only-buffering-ha.aspx).*